# Getting a jittery nav bar movement on Chrome iphone with css fixed

Tags: html, css, ios

Testing my site out on Chrome on iphone I am getting a jittery movement on my nav bar as the url bar is shown and hidden. I created a video
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WekVV.jpg
Also the site is live at https://secretchickens.com/

I am using the code for my nav bar and then an input inside.

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
float: none;
top: 0;
background: white;
height: 8rem;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 1.4rem;
border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #ebebeb;
```

I have checked out other sites on my iphone with a fixed nav bar that don't seem to have this jittery movement.

Answer (score 0):

I had two fixed elements for the header.